# Ruby storing pairs, arrays?

Tags: ruby

I am currently trying to get my head around Ruby and implementing a basic TCP chatroom. From looking online I have found this part of code: (http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-tcp-chat/)

```
def initialize(port)
    @server = TCPServer.open("localhost", 8888)
    @connections = Hash.new
    @rooms = Hash.new
    @clients = Hash.new
    @connections[:server] = @server
    @connections[:rooms] = @rooms
    @connections[:clients] = @clients
    run
end
```

I am struggling to understand `@connections[:server] = @server`.

I need to keep track of what user is in what room. I was thinking of having a pair of client/room but am unsure of how to go about this. Would anyone have any advice?

Comment: The site you linked appears to have a fairly complete tutorial. You may want to review some more basic Ruby before jumping into something like this. To answer your question, that line is only attaching the server to the connections hash, so it can be accessed as @connections[:server] (remember that `:server` is a constant, similar to `"server"`, but somewhat more efficient)

Answer (score 1):

i would use a hash of client -> room

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what @connections[:clients][handle] = client is doing? Is it a putting a pair handle/client into the :clients hash?

Answer (score 1):

`@connections` is a Hash.

This line `@connections[:server] = @server` adds a key (`:server`) value (`@server`) pair to the Hash
Then `@connections` may look like this:

```
{:server => @server}
```

`@connections[:clients][:handle] = client` is setting a nested Hash
So `@connections` become:

```
{ 
   :server => @server,
   :clients => { :handle => client } 
}
```

**Note:** This is just for understanding, the actual Hash object representation will look different.